# How to debug retain count using ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC on my iPhone app and I'm trying to catch a bug that gives me the following output (with `NSZombieEnabled, MallocStackLogging and guard malloc`):

```
*** -[MyCustomClass retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x534e00
```

How can I track a retain count using ARC? What do I do using LLDB console with the `instance 0x534e00` (of course any other instance that will appear) in order to find the deallocated instance?

For the record: I'm not using any `retain` anywhere in my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Use Instrument's "Zombies" tool?

Comment: If you're using ARC, why is a retain message sent to your custom class? However you should change it to a strong reference with the __strong qualifier.

Comment: I'm not using retain, but strong. That's why I'm tripped by this message.

Comment: Don't use explicit calls when using ARC. You cannot call retain, copy, mutable copy, autorelease or release when you use ARC. Hence, delete the statement [MyCustomClass retain].

Comment: Check out this tutorial for using the Zombies instrument: http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Comment: Thanks for the link on Zombies.

Comment: xCode 4.5 doesn't have the option Run to open up instrument running on the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean that YOU are explicitly writing `[MyCustomClass retain]`. The system is doing that for you. You should use Zombies and Instruments and try to track the problem. At least you know that the problem is with `MyCustomClass`, which narrows things.

Comment: I was reading that NSZombiesEnabled doesn't run on the iPhone, but only in the Simulador. How to star the app on the simulator using the Instruments tool? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Your choices are: 1. Don't use ARC, or 2. Use ARC. But you can't do both. You can't use non-ARC retain functions while using ARC.